# What happens when I restore my windows (Linux) system back to my hard disc, when I didn't do disc defrag？

Tags: linux, windows, defragment

An intersting question is now surrounding me:

1) First I didn't do any disc defrag and I did a backup with Windows Image Tool for my current system.

2) Then after a long time, I restored from the backup.

My question is: ***What will happen if I directly do a restore step from the backup？***

A. The whole hard disc is of fragments, like what it used to be before. Because the backup is "of full of fragments".

B. The backup will read sequential binary data to package them into a backup file, no matter where they are. And when I restore from it, the package will be extracted automatically to cover up the original data on my hard disc, so the restored system should be of no fragments for the system itself.

2) What about for the Linux or Windows?

Comment: Windows: Not necessary to defrag before backup, it will restore just fine but will be fragmented exactly as it was when the image was made. Linux: dunno.

Comment: This depends entirely on the backup method. any method that uses imaging will write the files back to the exact same (fragmented) state they were in, whereas a file-copy style restore will allocate new file storage, ignoring the existing footprint of the file.

Comment: @FrankThomas：So you mean the Windows backup is still of fragments？

Answer (score 0):

if your backup is [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) based backup (as your appears to be from your description) yes, any [fragged files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_fragmentation) on the disk at the time the image was created, will be fragged at the time the backup is restored.

An image is an exact duplicate of the binary layout of a disk. it has expresses the exact same bit values at exactly the same places (well, at the same addresses, based on the same [logical addressing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector))  as the original disk.

Imaging occurs below the [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) and [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) level, so you can image broken or even deleted partitions/filesystems, or disks with deleted files, such that the file could be un-deleted later. In fact the recommended course of action for recovering data from a failing hard disk, is to take an image of it with a specialized imager like [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/), to move the raw data to solid hardware before attempting [partition/filesystem](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)/[file](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) level recovery. Imagers just don't care about anything, except the most basic of [disk geometry information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector).

Its important to understand that there isn't really such a thing as an "empty" area of a disk. From a digital perspective, Every single "bit" of the disk has a binary value. That value may mean "there's no data I recognize here", but it takes higher-layer structures like partitions and filesystems to give that value meaning; at the raw level, its all just pluses and minuses, so there is no distinguishable difference between free space and a file.

When an image is restored, a [low level write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) to the raw hard disk (with no filesystem or even partition awareness) is performed, writing the exact binary of the image to the disk, starting at the specified offset(for the specified length). it just writes 1's and 0's from the image to the disk, in order from the very first bit of the very first sector, on until the end of the image (or the specified length is reached).

There are some sophisticated imagers that perform tricks for backup compression like aliasing empty sectors, ignoring non-filesystem data, or even ones that know your OS so well that they can exclude data, extract only the kernel, or drivers, substitute SSIDs, change admin passwords, etc, and this class of tool could conceivably de-frag data on write, but the caveats are many, and MS is incentivized to restrict their tool to single-PC backups. In particular MS would not like their tool to be used for cloning to other systems without limitation.

Regardless, based on your result, it is incontrovertible that MS's backup tools are not performing defragmentation (I suppose they would call it block reordering) on imaging or restoration. I'm guessing that the obscene amount or RAM or temporary disk storage that would be required to defrag on the fly is the primary motivation, but we cannot say for sure. Either way, the technical obstacles are non-trivial.